# Find the points of intersection of the line

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the points of intersection of the line $0=Re \{(1+4i)z+2−3i\}$ with the circumference

$|z−6|= \frac{1}{√3}|z+2i|$
To find the expression for the line I did it like this,

We define $ z=a+bi$, then substituting

$0=Re{(1+4i)z+2−3i}=Re{(1+4i)(a+bi)+2−3i}=Re{(2+a−4b)+(−3+4a+ b)i}==2+a−4b=0
$

$⇒b=\frac{1}{4}a+\frac{1}{2} 
$

Can you help me with this exercise? it's too complicated. please

Answer (score 1):

First, since $z$ is a variable, not a constant, it might be more intuitive to render $z$ as $x+iy$ rather than as $a+bi$. With that rendering you will get the equation of the line in the more familiar form

$$ y=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}$$

Then the second equation becomes

$$ |x-6+iy|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|x+(y+2)i| $$

Which is

$$\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2}$$

Squaring gives

$$ (x-6)^2+y^2= \frac{1}{3}\cdot[x^2+(y+2)^2]$$

Which resolves to

$$\left(x-9\right)^{2}+\left(y-1\right)^{2}=30$$

Replace $x$ with $4y-2$ and solve for $x$ and $y$ to get the intersection points.

It's a rather messy expression involving $\sqrt{461}$ but is easily checked using graphing software such as at desmos dot com.

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace? Where do I enter those values? which are? I appreciate your help with this exercise.

Comment: You replace the $x$ in the last equation with $4y-2$ which gives you a quadratic equation in $y$. You simplify that equation and use the quadratic formula  to solve for $y$. Then you plug those two values into $x=4y-2$ to get the corresponding values for $x$. That's basic elementary algebra.

Comment: $ (4y-2-9)^2+(y-1)^2=30$?

Comment: Please. I need your help. no one else has been able to explain to me

Comment: Now you need to simplify the expression and solve for $y$. You can do that on your own.

Comment: Is correct?$(4y-11)^2+(y-1)^2=30$

Comment: Is correct?$(4y-11)^2+(y-1)^2=30  $  $= 16b^2-88b+121+b^2-2b+1=30$

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be available to walk you through the solution step-by-step. I suspect you need a tutor who can be available to help you face-to-face.

Comment: $= 18b^2-90b+123=30$

Comment: Please, I beg you to help me with this exercise. I am practicing for an exam. I am very interested in learning. By explaining this exercise to me step by step, I will already know how to proceed with the others who have sent me homework. I beg you